# Extract records of last 3 years from the current date as well as future effective date in sql

Tags: database, db2, db2-400

this is my table.

```
cid name dob(timstamp dtype)(dd-mm-yyyy)
101  x    11-02-2015
333  c    22-12-2017
301  y    12-12-2018
901  z    21-07-2019
111  a    02-07-2020
222  b    31-12-9999
333  c    22-12-2025
112  c    21-02-2016
```

this is my table. i want to extract records of last 3 years from the current date as well as future effective date. so my output should be

```
 cid name dob(timstamp dtype)
333  c    22-12-2017............(current year-3)
301  y    12-12-2018............(current year-2)
901  z    21-07-2019............(current year-1)
111  a    02-07-2020.............current year
222  b    31-12-9999.............future year
333  c    22-12-2025.............future year
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dob > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR;
```

use `CURRENT_DATE` if you want to get it from the start of each day.

If you want only year to be accounted:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE year(dob) >= year(NOW()) - 3;
```

Comment: Yep. But you had mysql in your tags. That will work for mysql.

Comment: Use the second query. DB2 has `year` function too.

Comment: I also want the entire records of the past year...so for past 3years it should start from 01/01/2017 to the future, and  now() is not working here

Answer (score 1):

For db2 this should be the correct syntax.

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dob > CURRENT DATE - 3 YEARS
```

If you would like the begining of your inteval to start with the first of January :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dob > DATE(RTRIM(CHAR(YEAR(CURRENT DATE)-3)) || '-01-01')
```

Comment: I also want the entire records of the past year...so for past 3years it should start from 01/01/2017 to the future